# Reset elements of only one fieldset

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have different **fieldset** having **checkboxes** in a form and for every fieldset I have one **reset** button but when I click on reset button every checkbox resets.. what javascript code should I use????

Comment: Please show your (relevant) HTML.

Comment: You can find all the checkboxes within a fieldset and set `button.checked = button.defaultChecked;` to return it to its default "chechedness" (probably not checked, but this will allow some to be checked by default).

Comment: With or without jQuery?

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch any how...

Comment: @DavidThomas posting some lines

Comment: `<form>
<div id="cssmenu">              
<ul>             
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span>Brands</span></a>
<fieldset id="brands_reset_field">
<input type="reset" id="brands_reset">
<ul style="display:block;">
<li>
<span class="check_filter_block"> 
<span class="check_filter">
<input type="checkbox" class="filter-value" name="Form1" id="Nokia" value="Nokia">
</span>       
</span>
</li>
</ul>       
</fieldset>
</li>
<li ><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span>Camera</span></a>
<fieldset id="camera_reset">  
<ul style="display:block;">
 .....
</ul>
</fieldset>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9MaLZ/10/

**JS + jQ**

```
// checking checkbox 1 for demonstration
$("#cb1").prop("checked", true);

// reset checkbox, closet to a reset button (up the dom)
$("#myform button").click(function(e) { 
    $(this).closest("fieldset").find(':checkbox').attr("checked", false);
}); 

// total reset
$("#totalrecall").click(function(e) {
    $(":checkbox").each( function() {
        $(this).attr("checked", false);
    })
}); 

// check them all
$("#iwantthemall").click(function(e) {
    $(":checkbox").each( function() {
        $(this).attr("checked", true);
    })
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="myform">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" />
        <button type="reset" id="cb1-reset">Reset</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" />
        <button type="reset" id="cb2-reset" >Reset</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" />
        <button type="reset" id="cb3-reset">Reset</button>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="reset" id="totalrecall">RESET ALL</button>
    <button type="reset" id="iwantthemall">RESET ALL</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't reset them to their default checked value, it will (possibly) just uncheck them all. It should check the *checked* property, as setting the attribute changes the default checked value but should not change whether the checkbox is actually checked.

Comment: And if the default was *checked*?

Comment: The OP is "on reset button every checkbox resets" not "every button is set to unchecked".

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly. Fiddle also. Have fun coding :)

Comment: RobG: did you read what he asked? "Reset elements of only one fieldset"!

Answer (score 0):

In plain javascript you can use something like the following. It resets all the checkboxes in a fieldset to their default checked state, whether that be checked or unchecked:

```
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
  do {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return el;
    }
  } while (el.parentNode)
}

function resetField(el) {
  var fieldset = upTo(el, 'fieldset');
  var input, inputs;
  if (fieldset) {
    inputs = fieldset.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      input = inputs[i];
      if (input.type == 'checkbox') input.checked = input.defaultChecked;
    }
  }
}

</script>


<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb0" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb1">
    <input type="button" onclick="resetField(this);" value="Reset field">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" checked>
    <input type="button" onclick="resetField(this);" value="Reset field">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: i think a jQuery oneliner does just that: `$(this).closest("fieldset").find(':checkbox').attr("checked", false);` :)

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch–so you load 4,000 lines of code to go with it, and still it doesn't work like a reset button.

Comment: Resetting a form control sets it back to its default value. In the case of a checkbox, it may be checked by default. By setting the attribute, you are potentially changing the default. You should be setting the checked **property** to the **defaultChecked** value. In jQuery it's: `$(this).closest('fieldset').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){this.checked = this.defaultChecked;});` and once you have the fieldset in plain JS it can be `[].slice.call(fieldset.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')).forEach(function(el){el.checked=el.defaultChecked;})` but I'm not that into code golf.

Comment: I like your jQuery solution for taking the defaultChecked state into account. +1